# How to show images in thymeleaf that are not in static folder in src

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm uploading images to a folder productImages which is not in the src folder of spring boot project. I'm storing the paths of each image. How can i use th:src=@{product.image} to display the image where product.image is the path from database(e.g productImages/photo.jpg). My problem is getting the location to the folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you wish to specify server-relative links in Thymeleaf. (as opposed to context-relative). Basically, when you want to specify a resource outside of the application context, but relative to the server, you use the tilde notation. So, instead of:

```
th:src="@{/product.image}"
```

you should use:

```
th:src="@{~/product.image}"
```

You will find very nice clear & concrete examples with explanation at:

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html.

Hope this helps! :)